# Not in and Exists not working as i expect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

all. My question is easy, but I can't solve it by myselft. 
I have 2 tables: et_pics.ob_no where ob_no is user id and et_thanks_2014 where thnk.e_to is a link to et_pics.ob_no. 
I need to find out ob_no in et_pics who absent in e_to in et_thanks_2014.

```
SELECT pics.ob_no, thnk.e_to FROM et_pics pics 
left join et_thanks_2014 thnk on thnk.e_to = pics.ob_no
WHERE e_to is null
```

This code works, but I thinks it's not the best way to solve my task. I've tried to solve it with IN predict:

```
SELECT pics.ob_no FROM et_pics pics 
WHERE pics.ob_no  in ((SELECT e_to FROM et_thanks_2014))
```

and not exists

```
SELECT ob_no from et_pics
WHERE not exists (SELECT DISTINCT (e_to) FROM et_thanks_2014 thnk)
```

but both returns nothing. Why?

Comment: Are there rows in `et_thanks_2014` with a `NULL` `e_to` value? Also, as a side note, there's no need for `DISTINCT` (nor a column list) for a subquery using `EXISTS` - at best, it does nothing. At worst, it may cause the system to waste effort. `EXISTS` is satisfied as soon as it locates a single row that matches the criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need correlation.  For instance:

```
SELECT ob_no
from et_pics
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM et_thanks_2014 thnk WHERE thnk.e_to = pics.ob_no);
```

Without correlation, your subquery (presumably) always returns at least one row, assuming the table is not empty.  Hence, `not exists` always returns false.

The equivalent `not in` is:

```
SELECT ob_no
FROM et_pics
WHERE pics.ob_no NOT IN (SELECT thnk.e_to FROM et_thanks_2014 thnk);
```

Is almost equivalent.  However, if `thnk.e_to` is *ever* `NULL`, then it will never return true, so everything will be filtered.  Hence, I tend to recommend `NOT IN` or `LEFT JOIN` for semantic reasons.

Also note that `DISTINCT` is unnecessary in subqueries using `IN` or `EXISTS`.

Comment: I want to thank all in this topic for help, but Gordon Linoff's answer explains better than others, so accepted as asnswer here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be using `NOT IN` rather like below since you are trying to get the uncommon values

```
SELECT pics.ob_no FROM et_pics pics 
WHERE pics.ob_no  NOT IN (SELECT e_to FROM et_thanks_2014);
```

Moreover, I am not sure why you think that your `LEFT JOIN` solution is not the best solution.

```
SELECT pics.ob_no, 
thnk.e_to 
FROM et_pics pics 
left join et_thanks_2014 thnk on thnk.e_to = pics.ob_no
WHERE thnk.e_to is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a fitting Where clause:

```
SELECT pics.ob_no FROM et_pics pics 
WHERE pics.ob_no  in ((SELECT e_to FROM et_thanks_2014 thnk WHERE thnk.e_to = pics.ob_no))

SELECT pics.ob_no from et_pics pics
WHERE not exists (SELECT DISTINCT (e_to) FROM et_thanks_2014 thnk WHERE thnk.e_to = pics.ob_no)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use "EXCEPT". The Query would be some thing like : 
SELECT ob_no FROM et_pics EXCEPT SELECT e_to FROM et_thanks_2014;

Comment: Nice idea, thank you, but there is one minus - I can't add more fileds in the first SELECT cause of "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists." error.